# Good Password manager for web developers specifically

Tags: password-manager

I am looking for a good reliable password manager for web developers.

Specifically it would need to segregate credentials based on ports or subdomains. I have multiple projects debugged on http://localhost:portnumber, and multiple servers like test1.example.com, test2.example.com. Credentials are different on different ports or subdomain. It also need to work well on all common browsers FF, Chrome, Edge, Opera...

Currently using Lastpass, and even so lastpass offers this facility it just does not work. ( it used to, but does not anymore).

All password manager give you constant warning when reusing password, which is good practice, but it is a real pain in DEV. So the ability to ignore ( and remember) these warnings would be great. Again lastpass does it but it does not work.

Comment: The easier way would be to edit the hosts file of your system and add multiple aliases for 127.0.0.1, then you could "assign" (just use it) each localhost service it's own "domain" and the browser password manager would work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Bitwarden](https://bitwarden.com/) is a widely known free password manager that works on all popular systems and browsers and supports various kind of URL matching:

- exact matches
- regexes
- base domain
  etc.

You can read more in the [documentation](https://bitwarden.com/help/uri-match-detection/).